# Will keywords written into a page using JavaScript replacing placeholders in the page source affect SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search, googlebot

Website pages use SEO content (words) that are dynamically generated. Like the store name (on a multi store site).

However the dynamically generated words only show when you **inspect element**, as below.

[image]

But when you **view page source** the dynamic content placeholder shows, as below.

[image]

Will this impact SEO, that is will the store name "Singapore" in the example be used/parsed or the dynamic content place holder or in any other way that I'm missing.

Comment: Does it have to be done this way?   Search engines are getting better about dynamic JavaScript content, but if you performed the replacements server side, there would be no question about which version search engines would index.

Comment: Unfortunately for now that's how it is, the module (magento 2.3) I'm using doesn't allow for backend generation, have asked the developers to fix this problem in future versions.

Answer (score -3):

Google will see it as "store_name"

Comment: Such a short answer is not high quality.  I also don't think it is correct now that Google is crawling and rendering JavaScript.    Please edit your question to add more information and explain "why".

Comment: Thank you will see how i can put together a non js solution.